# How to refer existing columns in data.table's set()?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a new column in my data.table based on existing column. Of course it is easy to do with `[` notation (like `iris[, newcol:=toupper(Species)]`) but I wanted to use `%>%` piping. This code doesn't work:

```
iris %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  set(j = 'newcol', value = toupper(Species))
# Error in toupper(Species) : object 'Species' not found
```

I can use dplyr's `mutate()`, and this works:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(newcol=toupper(Species))
```

But still, what if I only want to use `data.table` tools, without `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table::set()` doesn't recognize the column names like you want, because it doesn't use non-standard evaluation.

Here are a two ways to use pipes while setting new column names while using `data.table`.

```
iris %>%
  setDT() %>%
  set(j = "newcol", value = toupper(.$Species)
```

```
iris %>%
  setDT() %>%
  .[,newcol := toupper(Species)]
```

Both rely on the fact that `.` is a pronoun for the RHS value which in this case is the data.table.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table::set` does not use non-standard evaluation (NSE) which is needed to be able to reference `Species` as a symbol. You need to use either `$` or `[[` notation.

```
library(data.table)
irisDT <- as.data.table(iris)

set(irisDT, j = "newcol", value = toupper(irisDT[["Species"]]))
head(irisDT)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species newcol
#           <num>       <num>        <num>       <num>  <fctr> <char>
# 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa SETOSA
# 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa SETOSA
# 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa SETOSA
# 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa SETOSA
# 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa SETOSA
# 6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa SETOSA
```

If you really need the pipe and really don't want to repeat `irisDT`, then perhaps

```r
irisDT %>%
  with(set(., j = "newcol", value = toupper(get("Species"))))
```

but if you're using base-pipe `|>`, you can't use `.` so will need to repeat the name once:

```r
irisDT |>
  with(set(irisDT, j = "newcol", value = toupper(get("Species"))))
```

which requires *one* extra `irisDT`.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! I wanted to use piping and avoid repeating object name, so I guess I will resort to one of the options described above by @Ari. (not sure about difference in performance though)

Comment: See my edit, it removes the need to repeat `irisDT` when using `%>%`.

Comment: ah I didn't think about `with()`. Thanks!