# data.table's set in a loop

Tags: r, loops, data.table

Say I have 2 `df`

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(x = letters[1:2])
df_1 <- data.table(x = letters[3:4])
```

and I wanted to use `set` to create a new column in both `df` (but using an existing column as input)

```
names_df <- c('df', 'df_1')
for(i in names_df)
{
  set(get(i), j = 'y', value = toupper(.$x))
}
```

The above would give me error:

```
Error in toupper(.$x) : object '.' not found
```

I have resorted to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851939/how-to-refer-existing-columns-in-data-tables-set) and used `.$` but of course, to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `get`

```
for(i in names_df){
  set(get(i), j = 'y', value = toupper(get(i)$x))
  }

> df
   x y
1: a A
2: b B
> df_1
   x y
1: c C
2: d D
```

If you want `.$x` to work, you need to use the pipe operator:

```
library(dplyr)
for(i in names_df){
  get(i) %>% 
    set(., j = 'y', value = toupper(.$x))
  }
```

Comment: I too understand this works but is there any specific reason `.$x` does not?

Comment: The `.` symbol is specific to the margrittr `%>%` pipe.

Comment: @Axeman
I see. Many thanks. It was bugging me as it is cleaner than another `get(i)`
but to take advantage of the pipe operator, one would have to load `dplyr`

Thanks too, Jilber